# Guaranteed smooth surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, implicit-function-theorem

The sets $X_a$ and $Y_b$ of equations $x^2+y^3+z = a$ and $x+y+z = b$, respectively, are smooth surfaces in $R^3$.

What values of $a$ and $b$ guarantee that the intersection of $X_a$ and $Y_b$ is a smooth curve?

I'm trying to use implicit function theorem for this.
So F(x, y, z) = ($x^2+y^3+z - a$, $x+y+z-b$) = 0. (I don't know how to make vectors in Latex so forgive me for poor formatting.)

I calculated the Jacobian for F, all 1's in the top row and other stuff in the second row; row-reduced it, but don't know what to do from here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You know that $F^{-1}(0)$ is a smooth curve as long as $0$ is a *regular value*, that is, as long as for every point $(x,y,z)$ which maps to $0$, the Jacobian at $(x,y,z)$ is surjective (rank $2$).  From your row reduction, you can see that points of the domain which do NOT have rank $2$ Jacobian are those for which $x = \frac{1}{2}$ and $y = \pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$.  So as long as $a$ and $b$ are chosen such that no point of this form maps to $0$, you can say that $0$ is a regular value, and therefore $F^{-1}(0)$ is a manifold.

Comment: How can there be 2 linearly independent columns if the top row is all 1's? Don't I need at least 1 zero in the top row to have 2 linearly independent columns?

Comment: $\biggl(\begin{matrix}1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \end{matrix}\biggr)$. Any pair of columns in this example is linearly independent.

Comment: Two columns are linearly independent as long as one is not a multiple of the other.  In your case, there will always be two linearly independent columns unless your matrix consists entirely of 1s, which occurs at the points specified above.